# How to debug ES6 in chrome in 2018?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I have a ES6 very simple code using `express` and I would like to debug it in Chrome. In my `package.json` I currently have:

```
"scripts": {
  "server-debug": "babel-node --inspect-brk"
}
```

But when I load my debug-session in Chrome, I don't see my code, only a `_babel_node.js` file.

Similar questions recommend to use `babel-node-debug`, but this package is no longer supported and has been deprecated two years ago.

Comment: I don’t know about sourcemap

Comment: Well, if this is node.js, and you're using the latest version of node, you don't really need babel. Otherwise to debug it in chrome I think you'll need source maps, which take your transpiled code and "map" the lines back to the original source code.

Comment: I use node `v9.8.0` and it does not recognize `import`. Do you know how I should use source maps?

Comment: You don't **need** import, use `const {module} = require('package')` or just `const package = require('package')` --- I'm not sure with babel-node how things would work, but you can read about source maps for babel at https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#compile-with-source-maps

Comment: Well, in this case I am not ES6 anymore :(

Comment: I would really not consider that a true statement, given how much else is supported. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ There might be a flag you can set node to allow import/export syntax, but it's really only one of the few things not supported, I'm not sure exactly why.

Comment: Not sure of the specific details, having never used `babel-node`, but if you really want to use ES6 module syntax, look into configuring babel to only transform `import` and `export` keywords into CommonJS, and disable all other default transformations from ES6 to ES5, that way the transpiled output will be a lot more readable.